# leave a thread alive as long as its children are

Tags: java, multithreading

```
class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
      Thread parent = new Thread(() -> {
         new Thread(() -> {
            longTask();
         }).start();
      });

      parent.start();
      parent.join();

      System.out.println(
            "I want to run this line only when parent thread and all this child " +
                  " terminate (in this case after the longTask() terminate)");
   }
}
```

I feel that the solution is in the ThreadGroups...

For information, I cannot save the references of child threads, or add them to a queue

Thank you in advance, if you need more information, do not hesitate

[EDIT :]
Maybe it's a lead ... [EDIT: In fact it's a bad lead]

```
      parent.start();
      parent.join();

      for (Thread thread : Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()) {
         // verify if the thread is child of $parent, and join it if
      }

      System.out.println("...")
```

Comment: If you can't save the reference of the child threads, or add them to a queue, it is unlikely that you can make the threads part of a ThreadGroup since this is done at the construction of the Thread. I would change the requirements and use e.g. a Phaser.

Comment: How much control do you have over the `Runnable` running in the root Thread and do you manually create the child Threads or are you looking for a very generic solution handling every possible creation of threads within the root ?

Comment: I can only modify the code from a.start(); (included)

Comment: What you're doing is the Wrong Way to write code. You're trying to be clever here and you're going to regret it later. Your thread stack trace "solution" is a hack. Please reconsider your requirements as they are forcing you to write bad code.

Comment: @Qix-MONICAWASMISTREATED Yes I am well aware that using the stacktrace to get the list of all threads is a bad thing, but I don't see how to get the child thread reference otherwise.
This is not a solution, only a lead ... the leads can be bad, but it keeps moving forward

Comment: How do you propose to "verify if the thread is child of $parent?" The words "parent" and "child" may have some meaning for you and for your particular application, but most threading libraries and most operating systems do not recognize any such relationship. The only way you'll be able to find out whether thread A created thread B is if _your code_ recorded that fact somewhere when thread B was created.

Comment: @SolomonSlow indeed no way to check this ... for the moment I am still stuck on the problem, indeed the "solution" would be to register the child thread.
Here the question concerns only a small problem of a bigger problem, I understand that it seems to contradict or useless. Anyway thank you for your help